# ¿Qué tipo de oración es "se le vuelve a volar" en este texto?

Tags: sintaxis

> Iba entrando en su casa la tarde siguiente, miércoles, cuando un niño
>   de la calle le entregó la misma paloma dentro de una jaula, con el
>   recado de memoria de que aquí le manda esto la señora de las palomas,
>   y le manda a decir que por favor la guarde bien en la jaula cerrada
>   porque si no **se le vuelve a volar** y esta es la última vez que se
>   la devuelve.

Desde el punto de vista sintáctico el fragmento en negrita es una frase principal, ¿no? ¿O me equivoco?

Answer (score 2):

«[S]i no, se le vuelve a volar» es una oración condicional. Por lo general, estas construcciones consisten de una **prótasis** (la parte de la oración que introduce la condición como tal) y una **apódosis** (la parte de la oración que presenta la consecuencia de la condición). La prótasis es «si no» (que en esencia y en contexto, es «Si no la guarda bien en la jaula»), mientras que la apódosis es «se le vuelve a volar».

Comment: muchas gracias : )

Answer (score 2):

...le manda a decir

*CD:*{que por favor la guarde bien en la jaula cerrada *Prop subordinada adverbial de causa*: [porque *Prop coordinada 1*:(*Prop subordinada adverbial condicional:* |si no| *Apódosis*: ¦**se le vuelve a volar**¦) y *Proposición coordinada 2*: (esta es la última vez que se la devuelve)]}

En conclusión, es una apódosis, dentro de una proposición coordinada, dentro de una proposición subordinada adverbial, dentro de un CD y este dentro de un proposición coordinada, nada más lejos de ser una oración principal.

[image]

Comment: ¡vaya! esto sí es fenomenal : ) Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El fragmento es bastante complejo pero creo que te equivocas

> *porque si no se le vuelve a volar*

representa la causa de por qué debe guardarlo en la jaula cerrada, por lo que es una subordinada de causa. Todo lo que aparece tras *decir* es su complemento directo

> *que por favor la guarde bien en la jaula cerrada porque si no se le vuelve a volar y esta es la última vez que se la devuelve*

y dentro de este bloque, el fragmento que te interesa es la razón del verbo principal *guarde*

Comment: … uyy pensaba q la oración causal era solo la parte „xq si no“ (tipo frase elíptica: xq si no la guarda bien (causa), se le vuelve a volar“)...